# how to open write peminssion when ip from my side?

Tags: php, vps

```
www
    languages   // not writeable
    modules     // not writeable
    cache   // writeable
    admin // not writeable
    ...
```

for security , my company decide to cancel write permissions for some folders of our site.
languages folder changing frequently . I want to write an admin/lang_edit.php to rewrite code for languages/xxx.php
but now the languages folder has no write permission. I can not rewrite them using lang_edit.php.
any way to deal with this problem? or can it be that if ip from my company, open write permission ,otherwise close it.

Comment: You don't have option for changing write permission particular IP, because php is running at your server side and always running as the same user irrespective of from where the script is called.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with IP, you cannot do that. It has to do with the fact the PHP scripts are running authenticated as a restricted user, generaly the user `nobody` or `www-data`. It is standard practice to allow writing access to such user only in specific folders where its strictly necessary for the website's workflow.

It doesn't mean the FTP user shouldn't be able to write though, only the PHP scripts have this limitation. If you are required to have script writing access to some folders in order to do something in your website, you can just access with FTP and use it to adjust the necessary writing permissions.

If you need write access just to configure something, you can set them as writeable, do your stuff, and then set the restricted permissions back.